# Emacs: how to disable 'file changed on disk' checking?

Tags: emacs

How to disable Emacs from checking the buffer file was changed outside the editor?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Emacs is really trying to help you here.  Read the info page on [Protection against Simultaneous Editing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html).

But, if you still want to avoid that message/prompt, you can redefine the function that is doing the prompting:

```
(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat (fn)
  "blatantly ignore files that changed on disk"
  )
(defun ask-user-about-lock (file opponent)
  "always grab lock"
   t)
```

The second function there is for when two people are using Emacs to edit the same file, and would provide a similar prompt (but not the one you seemed to refer to in the question).

I'd advise against overriding the two routines, but it's there if you want.

---

On the off chance  `global-auto-revert-mode` is on, you could disable that.  Add this to your .emacs:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode -1)
```

You can tell if the mode is on by looking at the variable of the same name:

```
C-h v global-auto-revert-mode RET
```

If the value is `t`, then the mode is on, otherwise it is off.

Comment: The comes up a lot when running emacs in VMWare and editting files in /mnt/hgfs (links to host machine folders). VMWare's clock gets out of sync with the host -- occassionally, you can even see the result of time system calls jump backwards in time. 

So,... is it possible to disable the check only when editting files in a specific directory? (e.g. /mnt/hgfs?)

Comment: This workaround is also needed when using Emacs on Windows through Parallels on OSX to modify files on the native/host OSX.  In addition to modifying `ask-user-about-suppression-threat`, I also modified `basic-save-buffer` with a `defalias` and a new function that omits / removes:  `(or (verify-visited-file-modtime (current-buffer)) (not (file-exists-p buffer-file-name)) (yes-or-no-p (format "%s has changed since visited or saved.  Save anyway? " (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))) (user-error "Save not confirmed"))`.

Comment: Emacs should really check that the contents of the file have changed and not just the timestamps.  This happens on all my buffers every time I switch git branches temporarily and switch back (or git stash save/pop).  *Edit* have just discovered @doublep 's answer

Comment: For those that have issues with VMWare `/mnt/hgfs`, have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556894/450148

Answer (score 11):

In my case I wanted:

```
(setq revert-without-query '(".*"))
```

Documentation for `revert-without-query`:

```
Specify which files should be reverted without query.
The value is a list of regular expressions.
If the file name matches one of these regular expressions,
then ‘revert-buffer’ reverts the file without querying
if the file has changed on disk and you have not edited the buffer.
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Much better than monkey patching.

Answer (score 10):

I have the following in my `.emacs`. It makes Emacs only ask about really changed files. If a file remains the same bytewise, just its timestamp is updated, as often happens when you switch branches in VCS, this "change" is ignored by Emacs.

```
;; Ignore modification-time-only changes in files, i.e. ones that
;; don't really change the contents.  This happens often with
;; switching between different VC buffers.

(defun update-buffer-modtime-if-byte-identical ()
  (let* ((size      (buffer-size))
         (byte-size (position-bytes size))
         (filename  buffer-file-name))
    (when (and byte-size (<= size 1000000))
      (let* ((attributes (file-attributes filename))
             (file-size  (nth 7 attributes)))
        (when (and file-size
                   (= file-size byte-size)
                   (string= (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (1+ size))
                            (with-temp-buffer
                              (insert-file-contents filename)
                              (buffer-string))))
          (set-visited-file-modtime (nth 5 attributes))
          t)))))

(defun verify-visited-file-modtime--ignore-byte-identical (original &optional buffer)
  (or (funcall original buffer)
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (update-buffer-modtime-if-byte-identical))))
(advice-add 'verify-visited-file-modtime :around #'verify-visited-file-modtime--ignore-byte-identical)

(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat--ignore-byte-identical (original &rest arguments)
  (unless (update-buffer-modtime-if-byte-identical)
    (apply original arguments)))
(advice-add 'ask-user-about-supersession-threat :around #'ask-user-about-supersession-threat--ignore-byte-identical)
```

Comment: +1 This is very similar to what I was thinking, but it will only work right if the buffer doesn't have unsaved changes.  I was thinking I would maintain an assoc array of buffer SHA1s (or MD5 or whatever is cheap enough to calculate on the fly and robust enough against clashes) and update it whenever a new file is visited or whenever I save a file.  Then if the file with the updated timestamp has the same hash, the alert is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it's just as you described and has that unhandled case. But it's enough for me, because I have a habit of saving buffers often.

Comment: @doublep you are my hero!

Comment: This feature is now built in, starting with Emacs 26: [see the changelog](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.26#L556)

Comment: @Arkanosis could you be a little bit more explicit? Your link goes to line 556 in the document, but I can't see anything related to this there. I am running 26.1 and I still seem to have this issue.

Comment: @martinweiss : sorry I made the mistake to link to the master branch, which has changed in the meantime. Here's [the link to the relevant version](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7adf1a361db3a2e9b7a27d76946482276c24fb64/etc/NEWS.26#L556). I have compiled my own Emacs 27 on distros that ship older releases, and I haven't had this issue for months, whereas I had it every single morning before with Emacs 24 (some NFS issue, I guess).

Answer (score 9):

I had annoyance with this because every time I switched branches in git, emacs thought all my files had changed.

[Revbuffs](http://www.neilvandyke.org/revbufs/) helps you cope with the symptoms of this.  It allows you to cause all your buffers to be reloaded.

You can also try `(global-auto-revert-mode)` which will automatically revert your files to what's on disk.