# Emacs: fix 'changed on disk'/'Reread from disk' when file has not changed

Tags: emacs

Is there any way to get emacs to actually check the contents of files on disk when determining this?

E.g. if I have some unsaved changes to a file, and temporarily switch source control branches (to make changes to other files), then switch back again, I want to be able to continue editing where I left off without this prompt.
(the prompt would be much more trustworthy and useful if it only warned me when the file had *really* changed)

I think it currently goes by timestamp or something.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread entitled **Emacs: how to disable 'file changed on disk' checking?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2284703/2112489

Comment: Thanks @lawlist, read that prior to posting.  I don't want to ignore it when the files have actually changed.

Comment: Could I get it reopened @ulrich-schwarz

Comment: Could I get it reopened @tripleee

Comment: I agree @EoghanM that this is a separate question, but might be worth resubmitting the question on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ . I'd be interested in any answer.

Comment: Thanks rich, re-asked here:
http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/fix-changed-on-disk-reread-from-disk-when-file-has-not-changed