# Eliminating "File changed on disk" warning in emacs on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs, virtualbox

I am running Windows 10 with VirtualBox (5.0.10).  I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed as a guest OS which accesses the host OS via a vboxfs share.

When editing a file saved on the host (Windows) OS via this share, emacs continually gives me a warning that the file I am currently editing has been changed on disk (`File.txt changed on disk; really edit the buffer?`).  And a similar warning is given when trying to save.

This only happens when editing a file that is saved on the host OS, and I can't link it to any other software / process (for example, anti-virus software).  It appears to be related to differences in the timestamps of the file on the 2 OS's, though I do have NTP turned on in Ubuntu, and the error occurs even immediately after the 2 OS's were rebooted (thus I assume the times are as identical as they will ever be).  It occurs every time after the first save.

This question was asked, and work-arounds provided, in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284703/emacs-how-to-disable-file-changed-on-disk-checking).  However, the work-arounds given there don't satisfactorily handle the problem because they effectively just turn off the the safe guard of checking whether a file has been modified on disk outside the editor.

The real problem seems to lie with the timestamp issue.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you currently using a [time server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) with either machine? Doing so on both may fix your issue.

Comment: Both the host and guest are set to use the same NIST time server. I have tried rebooting each and immediately synch'ing them with the NIST server, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the cause of the resolution to the problem, but it has gone away (for me) with Ubuntu 18.04 installed on Virtual Box 5.2.22.