# Emacs: Cannot disable "file changed since visited" check

Tags: azure, ubuntu, emacs, cifs

I am running emacs26 on an ubuntu azure VM and am running into problems when trying to save files on a particular mounted CIFS volume.  Emacs will randomly ask  "has changed since visited or saved.  Save anyway? (yes or no)".  When saving to local home storage this is not an issue.  I've tried suggestions from this thread: [Emacs: how to disable 'file changed on disk' checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284703/emacs-how-to-disable-file-changed-on-disk-checking) but none have worked.  I have tried adding

```
(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat (fn)
  "ignore")

(defun ask-user-about-lock (file opponent)
  "always grab lock"
  t)
```

to my .emacs file and this does not help.
Suggestions?

Comment: Of course it is an issue: Emacs detects the fact that the file has changed through external means, so its buffer is no longer in sync with the on-disk file. In some cases, you have inadvertently damaged the disk file, in which case saving the buffer into the file saves your bacon. In other cases, you have forgotten about the buffer and made external changes to the file that you don't want to lose: saving the buffer in this case is a mistake. I would suggest that you should investigate *why* Emacs is warning you before going any further.